# Explanations over NULL, 0, nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, null, g++, null-pointer

consider the code

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int* p)
{
  std::cout << "pointer" << '\n';
}

void foo(int p)
{
  std::cout << "value" << '\n';
}    

int main()
{    
  foo( 0 );    // value
  foo( NULL ); // error: call of overloaded ‘foo(NULL)’ is ambiguous foo( NULL );

  return 0;
}
```

Here we can see a problem with choosing a right overload for null pointer, which can be solved by passing `nullptr` to a second call of the function `foo`, but my question is about something different ...

As I knew most implementations define `NULL` as just a constant literal `0` like (`#define NULL 0`), therefore it is expected at the compilation time to have a 2nd call be like this - `foo( 0 )`,

But the preprocessor gives some strange output (after running `g++ -std=c++11 -E main.cpp -o main` )

```
int main()
{

 foo( 0 );

 foo(
# 25 "main.cpp" 3 4
     __null
# 25 "main.cpp"
          );

 return 0;
}
```

What is `__null` here ??

Is this a built int type ??

Comment: Looks like that's implementation specific (note the `__`). Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @user0042 I'm using `g++ 5.4.0`

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/support.html (last paragraph) In other words, the `_null` magic keyword is supposed to prevent exactly what you're seeing (first considering `0` as integer, and only then converting it to `nullptr`).

Comment: The content of `NULL` is implementation-defined. So it looks like gcc just uses some sort of intrinsic for it.

Comment: @VTT — it’s implementation specific, but not implementation defined. “Implementation defined” in the standard means that the implementation is required to document what it does.

Comment: `nullptr` was introduced with C++11 making `NULL` and its token definitions redundant. If this is actually a problem for you and you have to use an old compiler then you should be able to disambiguate the call by casting the result of `NULL` to a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__null` is a compiler built-in.  GCC uses it to give better diagnostics.  The problem is that you really want to define `NULL` as

```
#define NULL ((void *) 0)
```

— just like in C.  But with current C++, you would not be able to write

```
int *p = NULL;
```

because unlike C, there is no implied conversion from `void *` to other pointer types.  So GCC implements `__null` as a magic null pointer constant which is valid for any pointer type, but which is not an integer.  As a result, GCC can issue warnings for

```
int a = NULL;
```

which would not be possible otherwise.

Essentially, `__null` is an early version of `nullptr`, but it is more conservative because it is merely an extension, not a language change.